# Reuse a Backbone Marionette Module on a single page

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm really enjoying Marionette and the structure it adds to Backbone. However, I'm a little stumped with how to reuse a Module on a single page.

I have a Marionette Module that renders and handles events for a category tree. I would like to reuse this Module on the same page, that would display different collections in different regions in the page. I came to realize that the Marionette Modules are essentially singletons on the Application object, which is also a singleton. I apparently can't create a new instance of a Module to display and handle events for a new collection in a different region. Likewise, I can't register and trigger events on the Module, because there is only one and the events triggered in each region would need to be independent of each other.

Am I thinking about Modules incorrectly? How can they reused on the same page with different regions / collections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of modules as namespaces.  You would never try to duplicate a namespace, right?  But it's very common to have a namespace expose public types that other parts of the code can create multiple instances of.

```
App.module('CategoryTree', function(self, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
   self.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend( ... );
   self.CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend( ... );
   ...
});

//elsewhere...
var workingCollection = new App.CategoryTree.Collection( ... );
var workingView = new App.CategoryTree.CollectionView( ... );
var previewCollection = new App.CategoryTree.Collection( ... );
var previewView = new App.CategoryTree.CollectionView( ... );
```

Comment: Thinking about a Module like a Namespace REALLY helps, and it makes a lot of sense now that you mention it. The module itself isn't exactly reusable, the power lies in what it exposes via its public interface. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** I figured out what I don't like about this... If you need a show an unknown number of category trees (in response to an AJAX call for instance) you are dead in the water.

---

I found one potential solution that seems to be working. Basically, a Module definition is just a function. Instead of only using that function when adding a Module to the Application, I define the function as-is somewhere else in the global scope so I can get to it.

```
Project.Modules.CategoryTree = function(self, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
  // ... module definition goes here ...
}
```

Any time I want to use this module, I essentially add it as a submodule to an existing Module or Application. Like so...

```
App.module("WorkingTree", Project.Modules.CategoryTree)
App.module("PreviewTree", Project.Modules.CategoryTree)
```

While this does reuse the module code by creating two distinct instances, it doesn't smell quite right to me. Is there a better solution out there?